# How to fix Panasonic Toughpad errors on Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

The app I have uses com.panasonic.toughpad.android.api, and is running the lates SDK, but there are a ton of warnings right now that it throws.

I'm not sure how to proceed with fixing them though, there are a ton and I'm not sure if I need to manually try to fix code or if there's an automated way to do it, like regenerating the wrapper or something like that.

Thanks!

[image: Examples]

Comment: First, please do NOT post errors as images.  2nd, Warning are Warnings, not Errors.  You can typically ignore them.

Comment: That wasn't my question though, I didn't ask if warnings were serious